# empty payload when receiving HTML mails with image in body and a attachment MULE

Tags: mule-esb

I'm using imap connector its working fine in all the scenarios but when an email sent with an image in the body and an attachment I'm getting empty payload from the imap listener.
if I send an email with an image in the body and no attachment the image is saving as separate file and content in the body as a separate file that's okay.

Did anyone faced the same issue or can anyone please provide a fix?

even tried `disableTransportTransformer="true` in imap connector its not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:imap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap"
    xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap/current/mule-imap.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd">
    <imap:connector name="IMAP_Security"
        validateConnections="true" doc:name="IMAP"/>
    <email:email-to-string-transformer mimeType="text/html" name="Email_to_String" doc:name="Email to String" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <flow name="emailprocessorFlow">
        <imap:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="143" connector-ref="IMAP_Security" responseTimeout="10000" disableTransportTransformer="true" doc:name="IMAP" transformer-refs="Email_to_String" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <logger message="initial payload## #[message.payloadAs(String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-variable variableName="sender" value="${poller}" doc:name="poller"/>
        <set-variable variableName="inbox" value="${username}" doc:name="email User Name"/>
        <base64-encoder-transformer name="Base64-Encoder-Transformer_Headers"
            doc:name="Headers Base64 Encoder" encoding="utf-8">
        </base64-encoder-transformer>
               </flow>
</mule>
```

email body should be extracted through

Answer (score 0):

The image is likely another attachement, not the body. Try to iterate over the attachements and log information about the message to confirm it:

```
<foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="ForEach">
   <logger />
</foreach>
```